# How can I sort input that sended by "cat" in pipeline to function?

Tags: bash

How can I sort the input from `cat` like that explained the following code (?) :

```
function sort_input {
output_filename=${1}
# How can I sort the input (What that this function get from `cat`) into `output_filename` ?
}

cat ${1} | sort_input ${1}  # I don't want to change this line!
```

The script get as argument: name of a file.

---

**Clarification**: How can I write `sort_input` function, so that, this function will sort the input that sended by `cat ${1}` [And will insert the result of the sorting to the file `output_filename`] ?

Comment: not clear, please mention more details in your post.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Now it's clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you want is pretty simple:

```
sort_input () {
    sort -o "$1"
}
```

`sort` will inherit its standard input from the function, so `sort_input foo < foo` is identical to `sort -o foo < foo`. `-o` involves a temporary file internally so that it works even if you are using the same file for input and output.

Answer (score 0):

**More option:** (without a temp file)
After that I see the answer of @PesaThe , I think that we can do it without a temp file, like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sort_input() { 
    sort /dev/stdin > "$1"
}

cat "$1" | sort_input "$1"
```

Comment: I used a temporary file for a reason. If you use the same input and output file, you create a race condition with this code.

Comment: I just saw your previous post discussing this exact issue. Read the answers you get properly! :))